# Groups in the Samba configuration

Tags: samba, group

I can't quite understand groups.
For example, lets say if I add the following into my `samba` config:

```
valid users = @users
```

Must the group `users` exist on my system or is a samba group itself?
And if the former, how can I create this group. via `groupadd -r users`?

After that, only those valid users in that group can browse files, right?

When I log in now as `root` to list all groups via `groups`, it just says `root`, nothing more, but I need to know all groups.

Comment: The `root` user is only in the `root` group because there is no need for anything else: all permissions are simply ignored by the system.

Answer (score 1):

1. The group `users` must exist in the system.
2. You can create a newgroup with `groupadd users`. No need to use the `-r` option to create a *system group*. You can add user to the group using the command `gpasswd -a username groupname`
3. `groups` command list the groups the current user is in. The full list of group is inside the configuration file `/etc/group`. Do not modify this file with a text editor: if you do some syntax error you may become unable to login.